# Question related to my laptop username being the author of commits

Tags: git, github

For some reason I didn't add my email properly under my github account. And looking at the commit history, for several commits, github shows **the username of my local laptop** instead of **my github username** as the author of commit.(As shown in the picture below)

yesterday:
[image]

Today I added my email under my github account and pushed a new commit. For the new commit, I now see my github username being the author of commit(as shown in the picture below). However, I'm still seeing my laptop username being the author for previous commits. Is there a way to attribute those previous commits also to my github username instead of my laptop username?

today:
[image]

Comment: Short answer : it's not worth the hassle. It can be done, but is there a specific problem posed by this difference in authors?

Comment: Why did you not add your email under your github account - I was not even aware that it was possible.

Comment: @RomainValeri not much actually. Just wondering if there is a easy way to unify it. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: @Nelles I'm using github enterprise and I'm also not so sure about it..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commits embed the author name into their hash, this can't be changed. You *could*, however, recreate commits with the same contents, only different authors, through rebasing using filter-branch, but these commits will have different hashes, which means *all the next commits* (so here if I got it correctly : basically *every commit in the repo*) will have to change accordingly.

Instead of going into complex rebasing or the even more heavy machinery of [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), I'd suggest either :

- consider it a non-problem, until *something specific* requires the change.

or maybe

- use a [.mailmap](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors) for your repo. It'll allow you to map both names to the same label for a number of commands (`log` being an obvious one)